# Decimal digits of Euler's number

Tags: calculus

The number of known decimal digits of $e$ is $10^{12}$. Assume we want to beat this record. 
How many elements of the series $e = \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$ do we have to add together in order to get $10^{13}$ decimal digits?
Any help greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Are there really $10^{12}$ known digits from e ? I thought, this was only done for $\pi$.

Comment: Shigeru Kondo & Alexander J. Yee did it in 2010 :)

Comment: You'd want to keep summing until $\frac{1}{n!}<10^{-13}$ ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remainder term is

$$\frac{f^n(t)}{n!}$$

Since $f^n(t)<e$, we get an upper bound

$\frac{e}{n!}$, which gets smaller than $10^{10^{-13}}$ for about $n=8.7*10^{11}$

This is the solution of the equation

$$(log(n)-1)*n = log(10) * 10^{13}$$

For very large n, $\ log(n!)$ is approximately $(log(n)-1)*n$.

Since n! is very large, I replaced $\frac{e}{n!}$ by $\frac{1}{n!}$ , which
 practically does not change the desired n.

Comment: I'm sorry for being stupid, but could you please explain how you got this one: $3.9$?

Comment: I edited my post. The solution still is not completely exact, but should be near the true value.